# Leibniz integral rule for higher order derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Just wondering if there is a version of [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for higher order derivatives. Specifically, I want to evaluate the differential
$$
\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau
$$
at $t = 0$ for arbitrary integer $k$.

**Edit**

The Leibniz rule provides
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau = f(0) g(t) + \int_0^t f'(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau. $$ Then, $$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau = f(0) g'(t) + f'(0) g(t) + \int_0^t f''(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau, $$
$$ \frac{d^3}{dt^3}\int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau = f(0) g''(t) + f'(0) g'(t) + f''(0) g(t) + \int_0^t f'''(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau, $$
etc. Eventually,
$$ \frac{d^k}{dt^k}\int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau = f(0) g^{(k - 1)}(t) + f'(0) g^{(k - 2)}(t) + ... + f^{(k - 1)}(0)g(t) + \int_0^t f^{(k)}(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau. $$

Does $f(0) g^{(k - 1)}(t) + f'(0) g^{(k - 2)}(t) + ... + f^{(k - 1)}(0)g(t)$ stand for a simple expression. Apparently, $[f(t - \tau) g(\tau)]^{(k - 1)}_{t = \tau}$ is not what it should look like.

**Edit 2**

What I have encountered so far is as follows:
$$
\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau = \sum_{n = 1}^k f^{(n - 1)}(0) g^{(k - n)}(t) + \int_0^t f^{(k)}(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau.
$$
Thus, evaluating both sides at $t = 0$, we get
$$
\left[\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) d\tau\right]\bigg|_{t = 0} = \sum_{n = 1}^k f^{(n - 1)}(0) g^{(k - n)}(0).
$$
Can't encounter what the right hand side is.

Answer (score 2):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER**, but a long comment.

Using Dirac deltas and Heaviside functions, this can be seen as follows; 
$$
\int_0^t f(t-\tau)g(\tau)\, d\tau= fH\ast gH, $$ 
where $\ast$ denotes convolution and 
$$
H(t)=\begin{cases} 1, & t\ge 0, \\ 0, & t<0.\end{cases}$$
This can be useful, because convolution commutes with differentiation;
$$
\frac{d^k}{dt^k} (fH\ast gH) = (fH)^{(k)}\ast gH = \sum_{h=0}^k \binom{k}{h} f^{(h-k)}\delta^{(h-1)}\ast gH.$$
Here we used that $H'=\delta$.

Comment: Nice idea! Gives something like what I get from direct differentiation.

Comment: Well, actually this is more complicated than what you got. But maybe the change of point of view can lead somewhere, I don't know.

Comment: Probably, it's more complicated, but it gave me a nice idea about another thing. ))